# Problem with mouse over in multiline series

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 line chart. I have copied the code from the block builder and replaced with my data. Although the code is working but its not showing the labels when i hover the line.

I want to basically get the label details when I hover over the line.

Original Block https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 12px Helvetica;
  }
  
  .axis line {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 630 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.Year,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });



    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2.5)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/f1339c2bc02857afdf65b8d572dc31e5/raw/72ad1af2eacc86575649ae015b433aacb37f3854/US.and.SF.Crimerate.csv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key !== "Year";
      }));

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.Year);
      });

      var companies = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              date: d.date,
              price: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });



      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        }),
        d3.max(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        })
      ]);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Crime Rate per 10,000");

      svg.append("line")
        .attr({
          "class": "horizontalGrid",
          "x1": 0,
          "x2": width,
          "y1": y(0),
          "y2": y(0),
          "fill": "none",
          "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
          "stroke": "black",
          "stroke-width": "1px",
          "stroke-dasharray": ("3, 3")
        });


      var company = svg.selectAll(".company")
        .data(companies)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "company");



      var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.name)
        });

      var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];
      console.log(totalLength);

      d3.select(path[0][0])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
        .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

      d3.select(path[0][1])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
        .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.Year);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width / mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
              bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                return d.Year;
              }).right;
            idx = bisect(d.values, xYear);

            var beginning = 0,
              end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
              target = null;

            while (true) {
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Move everything that depends on the data to the callback of `d3.csv`.
2. You changed the property `date` in the original code for `Years`, but forgot to change this part:

   ```
   var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),//this should be xYear
       idx = bisect(d.values, xYear);
   ```

Here is the code with those changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 12px Helvetica;
  }
  
  .axis line {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 630 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .ticks(10)
      .innerTickSize(2.5)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/f1339c2bc02857afdf65b8d572dc31e5/raw/72ad1af2eacc86575649ae015b433aacb37f3854/US.and.SF.Crimerate.csv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key !== "Year";
      }));

      var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              date: d.Year,
              temperature: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.Year);
      });

      var companies = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              date: d.date,
              price: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        }),
        d3.max(companies, function(c) {
          return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.price;
          });
        })
      ]);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Crime Rate per 10,000");

      svg.append("line")
        .attr({
          "class": "horizontalGrid",
          "x1": 0,
          "x2": width,
          "y1": y(0),
          "y2": y(0),
          "fill": "none",
          "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
          "stroke": "black",
          "stroke-width": "1px",
          "stroke-dasharray": ("3, 3")
        });


      var company = svg.selectAll(".company")
        .data(companies)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "company");

      var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.name)
        });

      var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];

      d3.select(path[0][0])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
        .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

      d3.select(path[0][1])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
        .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

      var mouseG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

      mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
        .attr("class", "mouse-line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

      var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

      var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
        .data(cities)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

      mousePerLine.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.Year);
        })
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

      mousePerLine.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

      mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
        .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
        .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "0");
        })
        .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "1");
        })
        .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
          var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .attr("d", function() {
              var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
              d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
              return d;
            });

          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              var xYear = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                  return d.Year;
                }).right;
              idx = bisect(d.values, xYear);

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }

              d3.select(this).select('text')
                .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Gerardo. One more small request, I am actually trying to change the color of the line series from orange to red but I am unable to find the code. Could you point out where I should change?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the comments, post it as a new question.

Comment: Sure. Apologies